# Show /hide warning messag based on filtered outputs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Please find the attached fiddle where I want to post a warning mesaage "No data to display" if the filter fais to match any results in the button clicks.

[Fiddle ng-repeat filter](http://jsfiddle.net/w0L4o8jm/)

I have given condition for both table and message so that they should be displayed as and when the clicks happen.

```
<div ng-show="name===null">No results</div>
```

The above message should be displayed if there are no satisfying data in the table based on link clicks,together the table should be hidden.
I tried to give conditions based on property `name` but its not working.

Comment: Tell me one thing, you want to display table if there are any filtered results. Otherwise you would like to display `no results`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes Correct @Mr_Perfect

Comment: I am unable to edit the fiddle. Is there any privacy issue? It says `No need for the HTML tag, it's already in the output.`

Comment: No privacy issues.Please check in Mozilla

Comment: @Mr_Perfect the error you mentioned is because jsfiddle promotes the use of `<body>` directly without needing to write `<html>` tag. You should be able to edit it though

Comment: Thanks for your help @tanmay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w0L4o8jm/6/

By default I am making filter with `Fruit`. You can change it in the controller.

Coming to the answer, Calculate the filtered items length according to the filter. If length 0 or name '', then show `no results`. Otherwise show results in the table. Just copy paste the below code in your fiddle and check it out.

```
<html ng-app="app">
            <a ng-click="name = 'Fruit'">Fruit</a>
             <a ng-click="name = 'Nut'">Nut</a>
             <a ng-click="name = 'Seed'">Seed</a>



<body ng-controller="main">
    <a ng-click="name = ''">clear filter</a>
    <br>   <br>   <br>
    <div ng-show="(name=='' || !filtered.length)">No results</div>
    <div ng-repeat="link in filtered = (links|filter:name)"></div>
    <table class="table" ng-show="(filtered.length != 0 && name!='')">
            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Target</th>
                                <th>Level</th>
                                <tr>
                                     <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="link in links|filter:name">
                                <td>
                                {{link.name}}
                                </td>
                                    <td>
                                {{link.category}}
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>

    </table>        

</body>
```

**Controller code**

var app = angular.module('app', []);

```
app.controller('main', function($scope) {
    $scope.filters = { };
    $scope.name='Fruit';
    $scope.links = [
        {name: 'Apple', category: 'Fruit'},
        {name: 'Pear', category: 'Fruit'},
        {name: 'Almond', category: 'Nut'},
        {name: 'Mango', category: 'Fruit'},
        {name: 'Cashew', category: 'Nut'}
    ];
});
```

**For Angular prior to 1.3**

Assign the results to a new variable (e.g. filtered) and access it:

```
<div ng-repeat="link in filtered = (links|filter:name)"></div>
```

**For Angular 1.3+**

Use an alias expression (Docs: Angular 1.3.0: ngRepeat, scroll down to the Arguments section):

```
<div ng-repeat="link in links|filter:name as filtered"></div>
```

Comment: I added fiddle in the answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Thanks.But what  $scope.filters = { } in the controller does ?You are not using it anywhere in the html

Comment: That is you mentioned in the fiddle. i just keep it. I thought you may have some other work to do with that

Comment: @forgottofly `clear filters` doesn't work (returns `no results`) in this example which works in mine. Clearing filters should give all the categories, shouldn't it?

Comment: My answer was already stating that. Anyway, you get the points, it's your day :)

Comment: Actually, I did it, as per the first comment to the question and see his reply to that comment

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0L4o8jm/8/)

You had a few issues in there:

- your `ng-controller` was on a `div` but you were setting `name` outside controller
- `<div ng-show="name===null">No results</div>` Here you were comparing `name` with `null` but you were setting it to empty string in `clear filter`

Hope it helps!

**Edit**: On `clear filter` it was not showing all the items. Fixed and updated fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w0L4o8jm/2/)

```
    <body  ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
    <a ng-click="name = 'Fruit'">Fruit</a>
     <a ng-click="name = 'Nut'">Nut</a>
     <a ng-click="name = 'Seed'">Seed</a>
      <a ng-click="name = ''">clear filter</a>
       <br>   <br>   <br>
  <div ng-show="name ==''">No results</div>

<table class="table" ng-show="name!=''">
        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Target</th>
                            <th>Level</th>
                            <tr>
                                 <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="link in links | filter:name">
                            <td>
                            {{link.name}}
                            </td>
                                <td>
                            {{link.category}}
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>

  </table>
```

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('main', function($scope) {
    $scope.filters = { };
    $scope.name = '';
    $scope.links = [
        {name: 'Apple', category: 'Fruit'},
        {name: 'Pear', category: 'Fruit'},
        {name: 'Almond', category: 'Nut'},
        {name: 'Mango', category: 'Fruit'},
        {name: 'Cashew', category: 'Nut'}
    ];
});
```